# Change laravel domain/public to domain/

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

May be it's a very crazy and basic question but I didn't find any related answer to this question`-or I have to learn more about googling-`.

So, I'm learning laravel and figured it out that I can manipulate my `URL` using route in `web.php` file`-for laravel 5.4-`

When I set

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
```

I can see welcome view in this URL:

`http://domain.com/public`

well, I need to know how can I change my setting that I can see `welcome` view in my simple domain name?

Sounds very easy but I'm confused.

Any help would be appreciate.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webserver documentroot should be in "/%wherelaravellives%/public/" folder! add "`/public`" in `httpd.conf` `DocumentRoot`!

And restart the webserver.